# Deploy Angular app to beanstalk using GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I have an Angular application which needs to be deployed to Elastic Beanstalk using GitHub Actions. I'm following this [guideline](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/beanstalk-deploy) to deploy by application to ELB.

**I'm getting an error:**

> No filename given, deploying existing version 1
>
> - [error]Deployment failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, TypedArray, or
>     DataView. Received type undefined
> - [error]Node run failed with exit code 2

Below is my `main.yml` file

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - dry-run-actions

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      # I'm removing the intermediate steps to make this code look shorter and these steps are running correctly.
      # In these steps I'm "Caching node_module", "npm install" and "npm run build"

      - name: Cache node modules
        ...
      - name: Node ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        ...
      - name: Do NPM install
        ...
      - name: Building application
        ...
      - name: Generate deployment package
        run: zip -r deploy.zip ./dist/*

      - name: Beanstalk Deploy for Climber Mentee App
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v3
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY}}
          aws_secret_key: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_KEY}}
          aws_region: "ap-south-1"
          application_name: "app-name"
          environment_name: "aws-env-name"
          version_label: 1
          deployment_package: deploy.zip

      - name: Deployed the test app
        run: echo Yeaahhhhh
```

[image]

Please let me know, what I'm doing wrong or if I am missing out on something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the GitHub market place guidelines. In that code snippet, the key to mention AWS region is `aws_region`, which is wrong. The key should be `region` instead.

[image]

```
- name: Beanstalk Deploy for Climber Mentee App
    uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v3
    with:
      aws_access_key: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY}}
      aws_secret_key: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_KEY}}
      region: "ap-south-1" // not aws_region
      application_name: "app-name"
      environment_name: "aws-env-name"
      version_label: 1
      deployment_package: deploy.zip
```

Comment: Where in the guideline does it say "aws_region" ? As far as I can see it says "region" everywhere?

Comment: @EinarEgilsson Sorry the typo is on the GitHub market place when integrating. I'm adding a screenshot in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. It was an error in my action.yml file, fixed in version 4 now :)